# trouble query for join two table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I have two tables, my first table is `piutang`:

```
------------------------------------------------
id    nmr_bukti     tgl_transaksi   customer_id
------------------------------------------------
1     2015RSV0001   2015-09-17      42
2     2015RSV0002   2015-09-17      42
------------------------------------------------
```

and the second table `invoice_detail`:

```
------------------------------------------------
id    invoice_id     customer_id      nmr_bukti
------------------------------------------------
1     1              42               2015RSV0001       
2     1              42               2015RSV0001       
------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get result just like this with condition customer_id=42

```
------------------------------------------------
id    nmr_bukti     tgl_transaksi customer_id      
------------------------------------------------
1     2015RSV0002   2015-09-17            42               
------------------------------------------------
```

How can I make query for this case?

Comment: Both your tables have nmr_bukti = '2015RSV0001' for id = 1.. So why is nmr_bukti = '2015RSV0002' for id = 1 in your desired result?

Comment: Which id column is it in the wanted result, the one from piutang or the one from invoice_detail?

Comment: I'm starting to think none it's none of the two and id is actually a row_number :)

Comment: The simplest way to get the result would be `select * from piutang where nmr_bukti = '2015RSV0002'`. Is this what you want? If not, by what rule do you want this record chosen?

Comment: And another question: Both tables have a customer_id. Why? Is it part of the key? Can there be the same nmr_bukti with different customer_id in any one of the two tables? And if so, how could this influence the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query-

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.tgl_transaksi, p.customer_id 
FROM piutang AS p 
LEFT JOIN invoice_detail AS id 
ON p.customer_id=id.customer_id 
AND p.nmr_bukti=id.nmr_bukti 
WHERE p.customer_id = 42
AND id.id is null;
```

Note: For better performance customer_id and mnr_bukti fields should be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
SELECT * FROM piutang
WHERE nmr_bukti NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT nmr_bukti
    FROM invoice_detail
    WHERE customer_id = 42)
AND customer_id = 42;
```

Comment: its work with SELECT * FROM piutang
WHERE nmr_bukti NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT nmr_bukti
    FROM invoice_detail
    WHERE customer_id = 42)
AND customer_id = 42; thxs guys

Comment: Why DISTINCT in the sub-select? Also NOT IN is a bit "dangerous" if nmr_bukti is nullable...)

Comment: It depends on just what structures, rules and protocols the Questioner is using.

Comment: It depends on just what structures, rules and protocols the Questioner is using.  DISTINCT is probably redundant in this case.  It may be marginally more or less efficient to use in this case, but it will a smaller and neater dataset, which I find often helps with designing, programming and debugging.  Judging by the context of the question I will assume that nmr_bukti is NOT NULL in invoice_detail.  I'm not sure what would happen in cases where it is null, but in the absence of a more specific question I'm prepared to make the assumption, and handle any follow-up questions as they come.